# Prevent Lucene Query Parser from Initial whitespace Tokenization

Tags: java, lucene

I am referencing the following stack overflow question.  [Lucene NGram tokenizer with Queryparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121571/lucene-ngram-tokenizer-with-queryparser)

It appears that the Query Parser will tokenize the query string based on white space, and then call the custom analyzer tokenizer.

Is there anyway to prevent the Query Parser from doing the initial white space tokenization on the query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be really simple.  All you need to do is wrap your query string in double quotes like this.

```
"Example Query String"
```